# Using json-spirit to read json string in C++

Tags: c++, json, json-spirit

How to use json-spirit to read json string in C++? I read the demo code. 
I find that:

```
const Address addrs[5] = { { 42, "East Street",  "Newtown",     "Essex",         "England" },
                               { 1,  "West Street",  "Hull",        "Yorkshire",     "England" },
                               { 12, "South Road",   "Aberystwyth", "Dyfed",         "Wales"   },
                               { 45, "North Road",   "Paignton",    "Devon",         "England" },
                               { 78, "Upper Street", "Ware",        "Hertfordshire", "England" } };
```

Can I convert a String into a json object?

```
char* jsonStr = "{'name', 'Tom'}";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

json_spirit provides `bool read_string( const String_type& s, Value_type& value )` and `bool read( const std::string&  s, Value& value )` to read json data from strings.

Here is an example:

```
string name;
string jsonStr("{\"name\":\"Tom\"}");
json_spirit::Value val;

auto success = json_spirit::read_string(jsonStr, val);
if (success) {
    auto jsonObject = val.get_obj();

    for (auto entry : jsonObject) {
      if (entry.name_ == "name" && entry.value_.type() == json_spirit::Value_type::str_type) {
        name = entry.value_.get_str();
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

You could also use ifstream instead of string to read from json from file.

Please note, according to [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5) a string begins and ends with quotation marks.

Comment: sjon_spirit is undefined and I cant find it anywhere in boost spirit...this boost s@#t is the worst

Comment: JSON Spirit is not part of Boost. It self is based on Boos Spirit. To use JSON Spirit in your project, please have a look at sprits readme: https://github.com/cierelabs/json_spirit#building

Comment: Maybe this Question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437893/what-is-the-json-spirit-linker-flag-for-g