# what is the json-spirit linker flag for g++?

Tags: c++, g++, json-spirit, linker-flags

I can't find this anywhere.

I've installed json-spirit on my ubuntu server with `apt-get install json-spirit-dev`.

What linker flag has to be used with `g++` to use json-spirit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only library [listed in that package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libjson-spirit-dev/filelist) is called `libjson_spirit.a`.  You can link with it by adding `-ljson_spirit` to your linker step.

Comment: oh cool, ty!  now I know what to look for in the future.  tyvm for the extra info!

Comment: how did you know that `-ljson_spirit` comes from `libjson_spirit.a`?

Comment: Check the description `-l` flag in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options): "...`-l` surrounds *library* with `lib` and `.a`..."