# fatal error: botan/botan.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors, botan

I've taken the great advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17437912/1382306), checked [the file list for `libbotan1.10-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libbotan1.10-dev/filelist) and found `/usr/lib/libbotan-1.10.a`, so I used the linker flag `-lbotan-1.10`.

I've successfully been able to code and compile websocket++, json-spirit, connector/c++, and `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`.

I'm now trying to use botan's passhash9 to hash passwords.

When I try to compile with

```
g++  -Ofast -march=native -o btServer broadcast_server_tls.cpp 
-I ~/websocketpp-master/ -std=c++0x -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ 
-D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system 
-pthread -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -ljson_spirit -lmysqlcppconn -lbotan-1.10
```

g++ gives an error on the `#include <botan/botan.h>` line, saying "`broadcast_server_tls.cpp:12:25: fatal error: botan/botan.h: No such file or directory`".

To install on Ubuntu 12.10, I did `apt-get install libbotan1.10-dev`.

How can I correct this?

Comment: as the error says, compiler cannot find `botan/botan.h`. To include file you need to have -I flag. In which directory is your botan.h residing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile as:

`g++ "whatever_source_file" "whatever flags you are already using" -I/usr/include/botan-1.10/`

Comment: strange.  i wonder why the flag can be used with other libraries in the style from the linked answer but not botan...

Comment: @Gracchus where it is used with other library? The error is pretty much clear and -I is the option used. Normally, linker would give errors like `undefined reference` which means that it already found the file(containing function definitions) but when tried to find the code for some particular function, could not find it. I guess if the path where `.a` of `botan` is present is not in default search of `linker` then you will get an undefined reference error if you remove `-l` flag for the library.

Comment: @Gracchus try adding `-L/path_to_dir` where `path_to_dir` is the path of the directory wher your corresponding `.a` is present.

Comment: yessir.  it worked.  tyvm!  i first took out the `-lbotan-1.10` flag.  gotta have them both: location & flag